# Need Optimized solution along with no jquery functions used

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, angularjs, optimization

I am new to angularjs, actually from jQuery background, I have created a fiddle which demonstrates the selected options in the array. But in between I have used the jQuery $.each function (may be have to use angular.forEach, but did not achieve the result),

1.Please correct me the functionality completely by using only angular functions,
2. And also please suggest me feasible/standard way of doing this feature. As this number of checkbox may increase or decrease along with the options in the select box.

```
<div ng-app="checkbox" ng-controller="chkController">
    Check me to select: <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected1" ng-click="getSelectedIds()" />Hello 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected2" ng-click="getSelectedIds()" />Hello 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected3" ng-click="getSelectedIds()" />Hello 3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected4" ng-click="getSelectedIds()" />Hello 4<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected5" ng-click="getSelectedIds()" />Hello 5<br/>

<select id="selectBox" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;" >
    <option id="greet1" ng-selected="selected1">Hello 1!</option>
    <option id="greet2" ng-selected="selected2">Hello 2!</option>
    <option id="greet3" ng-selected="selected3">Hello 3!</option>
    <option id="greet4" ng-selected="selected4">Hello 4!</option>
    <option id="greet5" ng-selected="selected5">Hello 5!</option>
</select>
    <input type="button" value="Show Selected" ng-click="showValues();" />
</div>
```

**And In My controller**

```
var checkbox = angular.module('checkbox', []);

    checkbox.controller('chkController', function($scope){     
       $scope.myArr = [];
        $scope.getSelectedIds = function(){

            $("select option").each(function(i, j){

                if($(j).is(':selected') && ($scope.myArr.indexOf($(j).attr("id")) == -1)){
                 $scope.myArr.push($(j).attr("id"));   
                }

            });

        };   
        $scope.showValues = function(){
            console.log($scope.myArr);
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M44RF/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've took your jsfiddle and updated it to be more angular way

http://jsfiddle.net/M44RF/6/

as you can see I've implemented 2 ng-repeat

```
<label ng-repeat="chk in dataForCheckboxes" style="display: block"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk.selected"/>{{chk.label}}</label>

<select id="selectBox" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;height: 300px;" ng-model="selectedChk">
    <option value="{{chk.label}}" ng-repeat="chk in dataForCheckboxes" ng-selected="chk.selected">{{chk.label}}</option>
```

it's because in MVC the View should be driven by Controller

[Information on angularJS $filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Cheers

Comment: excellent implementation, very clear and understandable, I think I have to learn ng functions first, Thanks a lot friend

Comment: Glad you liked it, if you need more help join us on #angularjs irc channel